# Command does not work as alias

Tags: mysql, shell, perl, awk, alias

I have this two commands that work:

```
awk -F'[= ]' '/^password=/ && p !~ /clientreadonly/{print $2} {p=$0}' ~/.my.cnf
perl -00 -ane '/\[client\].password=(\S+)/s && print $1' < ~/.my.cnf
```

they can grep pass2 from a .my.cnf like this:

```
# longer
# comment text

[clientreadonly]
password=pass1 # comment
port=3306
user=test_ro
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
password=pass2 # comment
port=3306
user=test
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But if I make them as alias:

```
alias mysql-get-password="perl -00 -ane '/\[client\].password=(\S+)/s && print $1' < ~/.my.cnf"
alias mysql-get-password2="awk -F'[= ]' '/^password=/ && p !~ /clientreadonly/{print $2} {p=$0}' ~/.my.cnf"
```

the perl one returns

```
[client]
password=pass2 # comment
port=3306
user=test
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

and the awk variant returns

```
password=pass1 # comment
password=pass2 # comment
```

Why is the result so different as alias? When I use the commands directly in shell, I get just `pass2`

Comment: Tip: `-00` should be `-0777`. The former doesn't actually slurp; the latter does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `$` because `$1` is interpreted by the shell:

```
alias mysql-get-password="perl -00 -ane '/\[client\].password=(\S+)/s && print \$1' < ~/.my.cnf"
#                                                                      here ___^
```

Comment: Or use single quotes, replacing embedded single quotes worth `'\''`

Answer (score 4):

Aliases are for simple commands like `alias lf='ls -F'`, for anything more complicated you should use functions:

```
function mysql_get_password2 {
    awk -F'[= ]' '/^password=/ && p !~ /clientreadonly/{print $2} {p=$0}' ~/.my.cnf
}
```

Not all shells support hyphens in function or alias names btw so they're best avoided for portability - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168221/are-there-problems-with-hyphens-in-functions-aliases-and-executables